# Documentation for Drupal 9 Views Advanced Relationship usage

Tags: drupal-views, relationships, drupal-9, documentation

Looking for documentation on D9 Views integration using advanced relationship features.

Finding it difficult to determine which outcomes are a result of not understanding the various id joins and which are potential bugs.

Willing to test and assist in documentation.

Comment: Can you add some examples of the sorts of issues you are hitting.

Comment: Hmmm, where to begin.   Because there are so many options from setting up the basic view (e.g. contacts vs say participants) it is easy to make the wrong starting selection.   Some basic guidelines on usage would help a lot because the wrong first steps can lead to lots of things that don't work as expected.   On the Advanced relationships there are a lot of options for selecting what I assume to be joins (to make certain fields available to the view).  But the terminology used is confusing and seems to overlap in mysterious ways.   This list includes over 50 different options in itself

Comment: Image of list of relationship option added above

Comment: So, any type of documentation that helps sort out choices to make to set up fields available for view.

Comment: Your attempt to add image may not have worked. The issue of which entity to start a View with has not changes between D7 and D9. Yes using relationships to set up Relationships can be confusing and the terminology has changed. Fundamentally, if you have a contact then you need to add the Relationship Type, then add the related contact to that Relationship. But to help give more explicit documentation will depend on what entity you are starting with.

Comment: am happy to try and take you through a specific example, which may then help build up some better documentation, or i can spin up a View and export it for you

Comment: Let me see if I can create some more specific issues.  I have had some success with basic contacts but there has been a lot of trial and error and guessing.

Comment: how familiar were you with this in d7? the key changes are that whereas the d7 Views integration had a lot of in-built joins for getting eg phone, emails etc, in d9 you have to JOIN those tables deliberately

Comment: Yes, exactly.   So, D8 made all entities eligible for joining and removed the simple built in joins.  We now have way more choices most of which have no value and overwhelm the simple stuff.

Comment: Perhaps documentation that specifically outlines how to do the 5 - 10 most common use cases would work.   Maybe a structure that allows others to add their "recipes" for specific use cases